# "uiautomator dump" does not show custom launcher or applications in dump xml

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Good day,

I have a custom android launcher I would like to test using adb. This launcher is effectively an android "Service" (android.app.Service) that renders a shape. Rendered within this shape are the available applications, rendered with their names and icons. Pretty standard. This all shows up just fine on my android virtual device (avd)

The problem is there is no mention of any of the outer launcher shape or any of its Image view apps in the uiautomator dump xml. If I am to test my UI I need to be able to assert against the current state of the UI which means getting this data somehow.

Does anyone know how to get the uiautomator dump command to represent *everything* on the screen in its xml output? Am I missing some programmatic registration step when creating my ImageViews and TextViews? Do I need to somehow register my overall layout?

Thanks for taking the time to read, any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution!

When dropping UI elements directly into the window manager (that is, android.view.WindowManager) outside of any android activity, make sure that when allocating your WindowManager handle instance, i.e. new WindowManager.LayoutParams(...) that the flag "WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE" is absent.